# Can I restrict the number of decimal places to two in the Number data type?

Tags: actionscript-3

I declared a variable of the Number data type. I want it to hold the decimal up to only two places. Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: Of course no. But that's not really what you want anyway, is it? You only want to display it with 2 decimal which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically one of two ways.

```
var n:Number = 1.005;
var decimalPlaces:int = 2;

// gives you a rounded String representation
var s:String = n.toFixed( decimalPlaces );

// gives you a rounded-down Number representation
var f:Number = int(n * Math.pow( 10, decimalPlaces )) / Math.pow( 10, decimalPlaces );
```

Obviously this is not in your Number Object itself.  And, since Number is a final class, you'd have to do inline code, as above, create a utility function, or put getters on the source of the values you need to work with.

So, if you want to use your values as Numbers, you'd do the `var f` style, and if you just wanted it for display, you'd probably use the `var s` style.